# Tomcat connect to Mysql load balancer

Tags: mysql, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to connect tomcat with mysql in a load balanced way.

Is this possible in Tomcat 7?

What changes are required in the following configuration?.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

i have 2 mysql servers localhost:3306 & secondhost:3306

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL manual for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html) indicates it's possible.

Note that you need to configure your MySQL servers to replicate with each other (master-master replication). You should use at least MySQL version 5.6, as it has greatly improved replication reliability. It is however still possible that your application will try to read a data row only written recently to one host which is not yet replicated to the other one, especially when under heavy load.

You may get better results with a proper database clustering solution. Have you considered XtraDB Cluster?

Comment: I am looking for the tomcat configuration to achieve this, I can configure master-master replication. Do you know the connection string to use?.

Comment: Have you checked the link? It is there.

Comment: Oh yes. It's there. Thanks. --> jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://[host1][:port],[host2][:port][,[host3][:port]]...[/[database]] »
[?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]